# Time lines for getting I-140 for US Green Card?

Tags: greencard

I am working under H1B in USA. I have almost lived 4 years in USA. Now I am planning to apply Green Card under EB2 category. My employer is planning to apply for labour on January-2016. I am aware that after labour I need to file I-140.

How much time it takes to get it approved labor and file I-140 and get I-140 approved?

Answer (score 1):

The best resource, IMHO, would be [trackitt](http://www.trackitt.com/). Since the actual answer depends on way too many variables, you should just go to trackitt and check how long it took for people with similar parameters as yours.